# Cannot redirect output when I run Python script on Windows using just script's name

Tags: python, command-line, winapi, windows-7, redirect

This is running on Windows 7 (64 bit), Python 2.6 with Win32 Extensions for Python.

I have a simple script that just print "hello world". I can launch it with `python hello.py`. In this case I can redirect the output to a file. But if I run it by just typing `hello.py` on the command line and redirect the output, I get an exception.

```
C:> python hello.py
hello world

C:> python hello.py >output

C:> type output
hello world

C:> hello.py
hello world

C:> hello.py >output
close failed in file object destructor:
Error in sys.excepthook:

Original exception was:
```

I think I first get this error after upgrading to Windows 7. I remember it should work in XP. I have seen people talking about this bug [python-Bugs-1012692 | Can't pipe input to a python program](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-bugs-list/2004-August/024920.html). But that was long time ago. And it does not mention any solution.

Have anyone experienced this? Anyone can help?

Comment: Are you aware that there are TWO output streams: stdout and stderr?

Comment: Yes. And I want to redirect the stdout output.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Are you asking about this?

> Windows: When executing Python scripts on the command line using file type
>           associations (i.e. starting "script.py" instead of "python script.py"),
>           redirects may not work unless you set a specific registry key.  See
>           the Knowledge Base article [STDIN/STDOUT Redirection May Not Work If Started from a File Association](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321788).

It's in the Python README.  Perhaps this patch is what you're looking for.

Comment: That's it. Just adding the InheritConsoleHandles registry value does it! Thanks a ton!!!

Comment: The link to the article is now dead. Here is an archive of the page: https://web.archive.org/web/20150403070207/http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/321788  Edit: According to the latest version of that page, the issue was fixed in a service pack for Windows XP.

Answer (score 8):

UPDATED ANSWER

A Microsoft KB issue ([STDIN/STDOUT Redirection May Not Work If Started from a File Association](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321788)) may be exactly this issue. The page has instructions for downloading a Win2000 hotfix, but that might not be needed on more recent Windows versions. After the hotfix (or possibly without it, depending on your Win version), a manual registry edit is needed.

You should check the link I provided; in any case, I summarize here:

- Open Registry Editor and locate the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer`
- Add a DWORD value named `InheritConsoleHandles` and set it to `1`.

That's it, supposedly.

Comment: I do have it in the PATHEXT. That's how I usually run the script. Unfortunately I got the same error with or without entering the .py extension.

Comment: @Wai: check the “new and improved” version of my answer, and let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Oops. Didn't see that S.Lott had already provided the same link. Sorry :)

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. Thanks. It helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to redirect stdout and stderr from the command prompt,
see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/110930

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of the issue, but I have an idea to work around it. Have you thought about adding a command-line option (like `-o`) to specify an output file that will capture the output?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. This will do as a last resort :) But it is not as effortless as just typing ">output" on demand. Plus I have a lot of scripts and it is not practical to change all of them.