# Save command line output in python

Tags: python, windows, command-line, background

I have a python program that runs command line (Windows 10), how can I save the output as a text file, also I want to run the command line process in background.

Comment: I'd suggest checking the answer(s) to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828885/how-to-direct-output-into-a-txt-file-in-python-in-windows

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to direct output into a txt file in python in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828885/how-to-direct-output-into-a-txt-file-in-python-in-windows)

Answer (score 0):

you can save the output of a command to a text file by simply typing `> txtFile.txt` after your command, like:

```
dir > text.txt
```

and for your task to run in the background you should use [Threads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) in python.
example:

```
from threading import Thread

def do_in_background():
    # your background task should be here.
    pass 

t = Thread(target=do_in_background, daemon=True)
t.start()
```