# suppressing print as stdout python

Tags: python

Ok.. So probably an example is a good way to explain this problem

So I  have something like  this:

```
if __name__=="__main__"
    result = foobar()
    sys.stdout.write(str(result))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    sys.exit(0)
```

Now this script is being called from a ruby script.. and basically it parses the result there.
But foobar() has a lot of print statments.. and stdout flushes all those prints as well.
Is there a way (besides logging mathods) I can modify something over here which automatically suppresses those prints and just flushes this result??
Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You want to shadow (or otherwise hide) the stdout temporarily.  Something like this:

```
actualstdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = StringIO()
result = foobar()
sys.stdout = actualstdout
sys.stdout.write(str(result))
sys.stdout.flush()
sys.exit(0)
```

You need to assign something that is file-like to sys.stdout so that other methods can use it effectively.  `StringIO` is a good candidate because it doesn't require disk access (it'll just collect in memory) and then is discarded.

Comment: awesome.. just what i needed :)

Comment: What about using `sys.stdout = open(os.devnull,'w')` instead of `StringIO()`?

Comment: @ovgolovin - definitely reasonable as well if there's no expectation you might ever need the output.  With StringIO you could retrieve it if needed before you reset the original value of `stdout`.

Comment: If you're on Windows watch out for Windows bug - [Cannot redirect output when I run Python script on Windows using just script's name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018848/).

Comment: for anyone coming along like I did... don't try this inside an ipython console :)

Comment: @Anentropic What's the problem with the iPython console?

Comment: @Dr_Zaszuś ha, I can't remember any more. I guess it blows up. I guess iPython needs real stdout to work properly. Probably if you isolated the lines above in a function it'd be ok.

Answer (score 9):

With Python 3.4 and up you can use the [redirect_stdout](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout) contextmanager like this:

```
with redirect_stdout(open(os.devnull, "w")):
    print("This text goes nowhere")
print("This text gets printed normally")
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import sys

class output:
    def __init__(self):
        self.content = []
    def write(self, string):
        self.content.append(string)


if __name__=="__main__":

    out = output()                   
    sys.stdout = out                   #redirecting the output to a variable content

    result = foobar()
    sys.stdout.write(str(result))
    sys.stdout.flush() 

    sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__        #redirecting the output back to std output   
    print "o/p of foo :",out.content

    sys.exit(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

[This link shows how to redirect stdout in python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2829036/724357). Redirect it to an internal pipe, then read your pipe and filter out the unwanted lines. That will let you keep only the lines you are interested in.