# Moviepy still prints a progress bar even after setting `verbose` to `False`

Tags: python, moviepy

I tried to suppress the console output produced from moviepy when calling the "write_videofile" method. 
I passed the verbose argument as False to no avail.
It still outputs something like:

```
0%| | 0/1624 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
0%| | 8/1624 [00:00<00:20, 77.64it/s]
1%| | 16/1624 [00:00<00:20, 78.31it/s]
2%|1 | 25/1624 [00:00<00:20, 77.90it/s]
2%|2 | 34/1624 [00:00<00:19, 80.80it/s]
3%|2 | 42/1624 [00:00<00:20, 75.91it/s]
3%|3 | 51/1624 [00:00<00:20, 76.07it/s]
4%|3 | 58/1624 [00:00<00:25, 62.44it/s]
4%|4 | 65/1624 [00:00<00:28, 54.77it/s]
4%|4 | 71/1624 [00:01<00:28, 53.63it/s]
5%|4 | 77/1624 [00:01<00:29, 52.69it/s]
5%|5 | 83/1624 [00:01<00:28, 54.06it/s]
5%|5 | 89/1624 [00:01<00:29, 52.80it/s]
6%|5 | 96/1624 [00:01<00:26, 56.95it/s]
6%|6 | 102/1624 [00:01<00:29, 52.38it/s]
7%|6 | 108/1624 [00:01<00:29, 51.74it/s]
...
...
...
100%|#########9| 1621/1624 [00:28<00:00, 51.43it/s]
100%|##########| 1624/1624 [00:28<00:00, 57.75it/s]
```

Is there any way to suppress completely the output?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9949633/suppressing-print-as-stdout-python

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update** - This answer is now out-of-date. Use `logger=None`, or set `logger` to a custom subclass of a [Proglog logger](https://github.com/Edinburgh-Genome-Foundry/Proglog) for more fine-grained control.

---

Yes.

There is  parameter in `write_vidiofile` and `write_audiofile` called `progress_bar`. Pass `progress_bar=False` to remove the progress bar. Usually you'll also want to pass `verbose=False` as well, like you have.

In order to get this functionality, you'll probably have to run `pip install moviepy --upgrade` (swap `pip` for `pip3` if using Python 3), as this has only just been added (Added in moviepy version 0.2.3.1).

The full usage is this:

```
clip = VideoFileClip("video.mp4")  # Generate a clip
clip.write_videofile("output.mp4")  # Prints progress bar and info
clip.write_videofile("output.mp4", verbose=False)  # Just prints progress bar
clip.write_videofile("output.mp4", verbose=False, progress_bar=False)  # Prints nothing
```

A `progress_bar` parameter should also be coming to `write_images_sequence`, we're currently aiming for version 0.2.3.2.

Comment: I accept the answer, but now I'm getting a lot of warning like:

`[WARNING] 2017-03-10T08:49:57.111Z 6ea1aca8-056e-11e7-bea1-ad162b1b8df2 /var/task/moviepy/video/io/ffmpeg_reader.py:113: UserWarning: Warning: in file /tmp/49502576-b270-4935-b087-26f4c08bffed/1.mp4, 1166400 bytes wanted but 0 bytes read,at frame 705/712, at time 23.50/23.70 sec. Using the last valid frame instead.
UserWarning)`

Comment: @anarchos78 Post that as an issue on GitHub, along with the code (and preferably the the video) that creates it. If it only appears when using `progress_bar=False` make sure to put that as well.

Comment: This has now been added to the released on PyPI version, so just running in the command line `pip install moviepy --upgrade` will add the `progress_bar` parameter to `write_videofile`.

Comment: @anarchos78, that error should be fixed as of the latest moviepy update. Please let us know if that is the case!

Comment: Is it just me, or is there no way to disable the progress bar for ImageSequenceClip.write_gif?

Answer (score 15):

Now in 2019 you have to use `clip.write_videofile("output.mp4", verbose=False, logger=None)` to hide progress bar, using `progress_bar=True` got an error like: `TypeError: write_audiofile() got an unexpected keyword argument 'progress_bar'`

Comment: _Still in 2019_. Interestingly, the function `write_videofile` actually takes `progress_bar` parameter https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/_modules/moviepy/video/VideoClip.html#VideoClip.write_videofile

Comment: Yes but, at least to me, that give an error, I solve that setting `logger=none`

Comment: `verbose` is not used anymore, it is all included in the `logger` parameter.

Answer (score 3):

To disable the progress bar or any other message from moviepy to appear make sure to set

> Logger to None

```
write_videofile(self, filename, logger=None)
```

Answer (score 2):

For moviepy==1.0.3

use

```
logger=None
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling `help(clip.write_videofile)` shows that:

> verbose (deprecated, kept for compatibility)
> Formerly used for toggling messages on/off. Use logger=None now.

So you have to set the parameter `logger=None`.

Answer (score 0):

Now in Moviepy version 1.0.3 its as follows:

**`video.audio.write_audiofile(audio_file_path.wav, verbose= False, logger= None)`**

progress_bar is changed to logger.
Just set it to None if you don't want progress bar.