# Python unittest print logging works on Linux but not on Windows

Tags: python, windows, unittest++

I'm trying to write a unittest that will redirect stdout and stderr to a file written on a Windows network drive.  For some reason, the same script (only diff. is the directory path) works on Linux but not on Windows.  When run on Windows, nothing is written to the log file.

Here is the script on Windows and nothing gets written:

```
import sys
import unittest

LOGDIR = r"\\windows\somenetwork\somedrive"
LOG1 = open(LOGDIR+'\myStdOut.txt', 'w')
LOG2 = open(LOGDIR+'\myStdErr.txt', 'w')

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):

currentResult = None # holds last result object passed to run method

def setUp(self):
    pass

def tearDown(self):
    ok = self.currentResult.wasSuccessful()
    errors = self.currentResult.errors
    failures = self.currentResult.failures
    print ' All tests passed so far!' if ok else \
            ' %d errors and %d failures so far' % \
            (len(errors), len(failures))

def run(self, result=None):
    self.currentResult = result # remember result for use in tearDown
    unittest.TestCase.run(self, result) # call superclass run method

def test_onePlusOneEqualsTwo(self):
    self.assertTrue(1 + 1 == 2) # succeeds

def test_onePlusOneEqualsThree(self):
    self.assertTrue(1 + 1 == 3) # fails

def test_onePlusNoneIsNone(self):
    self.assertTrue(1 + None is None) # raises TypeError

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.stdout = LOG1 
    sys.stderr = LOG2
    unittest.main()
    LOG1.close()
    LOG2.close()
```

The same script run on Linux works or would at least write to the files:

```
import sys
import unittest

LOGDIR = r"/tmp"
LOG1 = open(LOGDIR+'/myStdOut.txt', 'w')
LOG2 = open(LOGDIR+'/myStdErr.txt', 'w')
```

class MyTestLinux(unittest.TestCase):

```
currentResult = None # holds last result object passed to run method

def setUp(self):
    pass

def tearDown(self):
    ok = self.currentResult.wasSuccessful()
    errors = self.currentResult.errors
    failures = self.currentResult.failures
    print ' All tests passed so far!' if ok else \
            ' %d errors and %d failures so far' % \
            (len(errors), len(failures))

def run(self, result=None):
    self.currentResult = result # remember result for use in tearDown
    unittest.TestCase.run(self, result) # call superclass run method

def test_onePlusOneEqualsTwo(self):
    self.assertTrue(1 + 1 == 2) # succeeds

def test_onePlusOneEqualsThree(self):
    self.assertTrue(1 + 1 == 3) # fails

def test_onePlusNoneIsNone(self):
    self.assertTrue(1 + None is None) # raises TypeError

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.stdout = LOG1 
    sys.stderr = LOG2
    unittest.main()
    LOG1.close()
    LOG2.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the best way to do this, but it works ([at least on my machine](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/03/the-works-on-my-machine-certification-program.html)):

```
import os
import sys
import unittest

STDOUT_FD = os.dup(sys.stdout.fileno())
STDERR_FD = os.dup(sys.stderr.fileno())

with open('stdout.txt', 'w') as f, open('stderr.txt', 'w') as g:
    os.dup2(f.fileno(), sys.stdout.fileno())
    os.dup2(g.fileno(), sys.stderr.fileno())


class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_print(self):
        print 'some output'
        self.assertEqual('', '')

    def test_some_moar(self):
        print 'some other cool output'
        self.assertTrue(True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()

print 'I am printing to stdout.txt'
print >> sys.stderr, 'I am printing to stderr.txt'

# revert the File Descriptors
os.dup2(STDOUT_FD, sys.stdout.fileno())
os.dup2(STDERR_FD, sys.stderr.fileno())

print "Yay! Back to printing in the console"
```

Running this produces:

### stdout.txt

```
some output
some other cool output
```

### stderr.txt

```
..
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

### os.dup(fd)

The `os.dup` function creates a copy of the file descriptor and returns the integer of that duplicated file descriptor. So, after the first two `dup` calls, there are two file descriptors pointing to `stdout` and two pointing to `stderr`.

### os.dup2(fd, fd2)

The `os.dup2` function copies the file descriptor from `fd` to `fd2` and closes the file descriptor of `fd2`. So, after the `dup2` calls, `stdout` now points to the `f` file descriptor and likewise `stderr` now points to the `g` file descriptor (and because `dup2` closes the second file descriptor, there is only a single file descriptor for both `stdout` and `stderr` because of the copies made by the call to `dup`).

Print everything to your heart's content.

At the end, the last two `dup2` calls revert the file descriptors using the copied file descriptors (so stdout and stderr point to where you'd expect) which also closes files `f` and `g`.

According to the [dup2](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.dup2) docs, this works on both Linux and Windows.

### [Edit]

If it's not too much work, I would suggest not using prints and use `logging` instead:

```
import logging
import unittest


class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_print(self):
        logging.info('some output')
        self.assertEqual('', '')

    def test_some_moar(self):
        logging.info('some other cool output')
        self.assertTrue(True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    # get the default logger
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    # add a file handler
    logger.addHandler(logging.FileHandler('stdout.txt', mode='w'))
    # set up a stream for all stderr output
    stderr_file = open('stderr.txt', 'w')
    # attach that stream to the testRunner
    unittest.main(testRunner=unittest.TextTestRunner(stream=stderr_file))
```

Comment: I tried your code and it works fine on Windows if I'm not using it with unittest.  But when I use it with unittest, same result, it would write anything to the log files. :-(

Comment: import os, sys, unittest

    LOGDIR = r"\\windows\somenetwork\drive"
    STDOUT_FD = os.dup(sys.stdout.fileno())
    STDERR_FD = os.dup(sys.stderr.fileno())

    class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
     ...

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        with open(LOGDIR+'\stdout.txt', 'w') as f,   open(LOGDIR+'\stderr.txt', 'w') as g:
           os.dup2(f.fileno(), sys.stdout.fileno())
           os.dup2(g.fileno(), sys.stderr.fileno())

        # revert the File Descriptors
        os.dup2(STDOUT_FD, sys.stdout.fileno())
        os.dup2(STDERR_FD, sys.stderr.fileno())
        unittest.main()

Comment: Make sure that you have the `# revert the File Descriptors` `dup2` calls *after* `unittest.main()`.

Comment: Also, if it's not too much work to switch print statements, I would suggest using the `logging` module instead. You can create loggers and set stream handlers and all sorts of cool stuff and you wouldn't need to switch file descriptors.

Comment: Thank you so much as this is working for me now! I will try the logger class; however, does can the logging work well for logging unittest pass/failure and errors to a file?

Comment: Using the `logging` module, you can output any additional information other than what `unittest` will output. For example, if you want to print out some debug information, you can simply call `logging.debug('My list of stuff: %s", list_of_stuff)`. `logging` contains 5 helper functions `debug`, `info`, `warning`, `error`, and `exception`. Each have their own level of output which you can control with the `level` keyword to `logging.basicConfig()`.

If you want to capture all `unittest` messages (including errors) use the `testRunner` argument to `unittest.main()` like in my second example.

Comment: Thank you so much for the example on logging!

Answer (score 2):

There's an issue where on Windows you [can't reassign sys.stdout to redirect output when a script is started via a Windows file association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018848/cannot-redirect-output-when-i-run-python-script-on-windows-using-just-scripts-n) on Windows.  You might try the [Windows hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321788) that should fix it. Or you should be able to explicitly invoke `python yourscript.py` to work around it.