# error when pipe output to python script on windows cmd

Tags: python-2.7, command-line, xml-parsing, pipe, windows-7-x64

I generate xml content from input file using an xml_gen.bat file (I cannot modify it), and I use it like this on Windows cmd to generate xml:

```
xml_gen --options [inputname] [optional outputname]
```

I also have a python script xml_parse.py that parses xml input:

```
import sys
import lxml.etree as ET

def xml_parse(xml_input):
    for event, elem in ET.iterparse(xml_input, events=('end', ), tag='TAG'):
        # do something
        # write parsed content to file
        elem.clear()

def main():
    xml_parse(sys.stdin)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Both xml_gen and xml_parse.py work when tested separately, i.e., xm_gen can take an input file and generate a correct xml file; xml_parse.py (ran in PyCharm) can take an input xml file from disk and do the parsing correctly.

Since my actual experiment will generate gigabytes of xml from xml_gen, I want to pipe the output of xml_gen directly to the python script to process them.

When I tried:
`dir_to_xml_gen\xml_gen --option dir_to_input\input | python xml_parse.py`

It produced such error:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "xml_parse.py", line 77, in 
>    main() File "xml_parse.py", line 71, in main xml_parse(sys.stdin) File "xml_parse.py", line 50, in xml_parse for event, elem in ET.iterparse(xml_parse, events=('end', ), tag='TAG'):File "iterparse.pxi", line 208, in lxml.etree.iterparse.**next** (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:131498) lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Document is empty, line 2, column 1 ! System error ! 'SPIO_E_END_OF_FILE'

when I tried: `dir_to_xml_gen\xml_gen --option dir_to_input\input | python xml_parse.py`

it produced similar error: System error 'SPIO_E_END_OF_FILE'

I'm aware of the issues in [Cannot redirect output when I run Python script on Windows using just script's name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018848/cannot-redirect-output-when-i-run-python-script-on-windows-using-just-scripts-n/%22Cannot%20redirect%20output%20when%20I%20run%20Python%20script%20on%20Windows%20using%20just%20script's%20name%22%22), and followed directions here [STDIN/STDOUT Redirection May Not Work If Started from a File Association](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/321788), but didn't solve my problem. Thank you for your help.