# How to display python output in C# textbox?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I want to display standard output from python script in textbox, but after click the button nothing happend. If it's wrong how can I fix it or replace?
Example
I run my aplication in textbox1 i have nothing and after clicking button1 I want to have in my textbox1 'Hello' from python script

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                char[] spliter = { '\r' };
                int x = 1;

                Process python = new Process();
                python.StartInfo.FileName = "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python37_64\\python.exe";
                python.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                python.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

                python.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Concat("C:\\Users\\kamil\\source\\PythonApplication3\\PythonApplication3.py", " ", x.ToString());
                python.Start();

                StreamReader sReader = python.StandardOutput;
                string[] output = sReader.ReadToEnd().Split(spliter);


                foreach (string s in output)
                {
                    TextBox1.Text += s + Environment.NewLine;
                }

                python.WaitForExit();
```

Python script:

```
import sys

def main():
    print('Hello')

main()
```

Comment: It's the shell that knows how to interpret file names ending in *".py"* as python programs. You've turned ShellExecute off, so that doesn't happen. You'll need to fire up python and then pass it your script and arguments somehow.

Comment: I fire python and give arguments, I think so

Comment: Hi. Can you check this post? The link in the answer is broken, but I think the post can still be much of a help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018848/cannot-redirect-output-when-i-run-python-script-on-windows-using-just-scripts-n

Comment: The UWP is running in the sandbox and is different from the desktop app, you can launch your exe file by using [FullTrustProcessLauncher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.FullTrustProcessLauncher), but can't access the output from a UWP application. Can you tell us why you want to do this? In addition, you can create a wpf application to use Process api and then convert the wpf application to UWP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `python.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;` and `textBox1.Text += python.StandardError.ReadToEnd();` to your code so that you can also capture the errors in addition to the output. I would reason that it may not be able to "find" the file you are passing as an argument. Try adding quotes around the file path like so:  "\"C:\Users\kamil\source\PythonApplication3\PythonApplication3.py\""

Comment: It helps, but now I have permission denied to a file

Comment: Are you able to open the file in notepad and save it? Does your application require being run as administrator?

Comment: Yes I can open and save file. I run my app from visual studio code I don't know if it's as administrator

Comment: Try closing visual studio, right clicking on the visual studio shortcut, and choosing "Run as administrator" or going to your debug folder and running the outputted exe as administrator

Comment: It doesn't help